# How to apply a filter in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

My question is how do I apply a 5×5 Laplacian filter with 8 at the center in MATLAB?

I try this code but it does not work

```
kAvg = fspecial('average',[5 5]);
kLap = fspecial('laplacian');
```

Comment: Please gives more context. I see no image in your example. Did you look at Matlab documentation at http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/fspecial.html ? What do you mean with Laplacian with 8 at the center. Laplacian has a -1 at the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/fspecial.html#f2-266353), you can use `imfilter` to apply a filter:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
kLap = fspecial('laplacian');
filtered = imfilter(I,kLap,'replicate');
imshow(filtered); title('Filtered Image');
```

EDIT: I just realized what you were asking [for](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ippi/ippi_ch9/functn_FilterLaplace.html):

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');

% simple high pass filter
kLap = [-1, -1, -1;
        -1,  8, -1;
        -1, -1, -1];

filtered_3x3 = imfilter(I,kLap,'replicate');
imshow(filtered_3x3); title('Filtered Image (3x3)');
pause();

% another simple high pass filter
kLap = [-1 -3 -4 -3 -1;
        -3  0  6  0 -3;
        -4  6 20  6 -4;
        -3  0  6  0 -3;
        -1 -3 -4 -3 -1];

filtered_5x5 = imfilter(I,kLap,'replicate');
imshow( filtered_5x5 ); title('Filtered Image (5x5)');
```

Comment: @CharlesBrunet - of course it's not a Laplacian. Although the question is not very clear, to my understanding the OP asked how to apply a Laplacian filter with 8 at the center. Maybe the title should be changed to "How to apply a filter"?

Comment: Thank you for your help ...But is it wrong when I apply Laplacian filter with 8 at the center?

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just not a Laplacian, it's some high pass filter

Comment: Thank you. But when I apply this filter on my image .Image become smaller .I don't know what is problem??

Comment: Are you sure it becomes smaller and not just displayed smaller to fit the plot? Anyway, it works well here.