# Filtering an image in the DFT domain in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, filter, dft

I want to apply the following filter to an image:

```
h = [1/4 1/16 1/4; 
     1/16 1/8 1/16; 
     1/4 1/16 1/4;]
```

I follow the steps bellow but i don't get the correct result. Can anyone help me? I can't find what is wrong with my steps. Here is the code:

```
I = imread('cameraman512.jpg');
h = [1/4 1/16 1/4; 1/16 1/8 1/16; 1/4 1/16 1/4;]

%padding image
Ip = padarray(I,[512 512],'post');
figure();
imshow(Ip);

%padding filter
Hp = padarray(h,[512 512],'post');
figure();
imshow(Hp);

%image fourier
dftI = fft2(I);
figure();
imshow(dftI);

% filter fourier
dftH = fft2(H);
figure();
imshow(dftH);

%shifting image and filter
I = fftshift(Ip);
figure();
imshow(I,[]);

 H = fftshift(Hp);
 figure();
 imshow(H,[]);

G = dftI.*dftH;
figure();
imshow(G);

g=real(ifft2(G));
figure();
imshow(G);
```

Comment: i have to apply the h filter in my image and show all the images step by step but i think that i have made a mistake and the final image is not the wright one

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583486/how-to-apply-a-filter-in-matlab

Comment: @macduff OP want's to apply filtering in the frequency domain, probably for an assignment.

Comment: yes but i have to filter my image in frequency domain. I must do zero padding, shifting the image, calculating the fourier transformation etc. there are many steps which in your example are missing

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you have a bit of work to do to understand what you are asked in this assignment. Here is an example of code to get you started.

Calculating the DFT of both the image and the filter:

```
dftI = fft2(I);
dftH = fft2(h, 512, 512);
```

Note that `fft2` has a built-in padding feature, that is what the 512 arguments are about.

---

**Edit** alternative padding per @OliverCharlesworth comment

```
dftI = fft2(I, size(I,1)+size(h,1)-1, size(I,2)+size(h,2)-1);
dftH = fft2(h, size(I,1)+size(h,1)-1, size(I,2)+size(h,2)-1);
```

The final image has to be cropped accordingly.

---

If you want to display the magnitudes of the DFTs, with the zeroth frequency in the middle, you can use `fftshift` that way (I'm showing them on a log scale for clarity):

```
subplot(1,2,1), imshow(log10(abs(fftshift(dftI))), [])
subplot(1,2,2), imshow(log10(abs(fftshift(dftH))), [])
```

[image: DFTs]

Since convolutions in the spatial domain are equivalent to multiplications in the frequency domain (with the usual restrictions, linearity etc.), you can multiply the DFTs:

```
G = dftH .* dftI;
imfilt = ifft2(G);
```

The result on the image:

```
        Original                          Filtered
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Note this will produce circular convolution (for clean filtering, both should be padded to N+M-1 first).